# C'ant post send post to api route using Angular http

Tags: json, angular, laravel, api, typescript

I'm trying to send values on a POST in the URL of a Laravel API route using Angular5. However, when I send the request, I get no errors in my browser console, but no network activity has been recorded. It's weird because I can print my route in the console and it is exactly the same as the one in my API. My route is 100% functional because it works using Postman. Please help...

Here is my favorite.html

```
<button (click)="addFavorite(stationId)">Add to favorite</button>
```

Here is my favorite.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'add-favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
   export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() stationId: number;
      constructor(
    private favoritesService: FavoritesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.params = params);
  }

  observable: Observable<number>;
  params: Params;

  /*this.params['id']*/
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addFavorite() {
    this.favoritesService.postFavorite(this.stationId);
  }
}
```

Here is my favorite service

```
@Injectable()
export class FavoritesService {
private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
private user_id = 2;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postFavorite(stationId: number): Observable<number> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/user/${this.user_id}/favorites/${stationId}`;
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.post<number>(url, {station_id: stationId});
  }
}
```

[Take a look at my console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GXV.jpg)

Here is my Laravel API route:

```
Route::post('user/{user_id}/favorites/{station_id}', 'FavoriteController@store');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the **CSRF token** on your request.

Ideally, you would write an **interceptor** to inject the CSRF token automatically, but for that specific request, you can do the following:

- In the `<head>` section of your Blade layout:

  ```
  <meta property="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  ```

This will place the corresponding CSRF token for you request in an accessible place for your script. I recommend you pass the value instead by adding a parameter to your root component.

- In your Favorite service:

> ```
> postFavorite(stationId: number): Observable<number> {
>    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/user/${this.user_id}/favorites/${stationId}`;
>    console.log(url);
>
>    let token = document.querySelector('meta[property="csrf-token"]')['content'];
>
>    return this.http.post<number>(url, {station_id: stationId}, {
>         headers: new HttpHeaders({
>             'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  'application/json',
>         })
>    });
> }
> ```

This will add the CSRF token from the `<head>` tag to the adequate header and send it with your request.

You can find more information about CSRF tokens in Laravel here: [Laravel - CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)

Comment: I tried it but it says : ` FavoriteComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null` when I click the Add favorite button @DfKimera

Comment: It seems it cannot find the `<meta>` element on your page; can you confirm it's been added and is present in the page `<head>`?

Comment: Is this in the file header.blade.php? This is what I wrote                                         
     <head>
         <meta property="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ 
          csrf_token() }}">
     </head>

Comment: I put it in every blade.php I found and still the same error @DfKimera

Comment: Try placing this tag instead: `<script>window.CSRF_TOKEN = '{{csrf_token()}}';</script>`

Then replace the third line of the function with: `let token = window['CSRF_TOKEN'];`